# Can <!--[if lte IE 8]> even work in IE6?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

I am just about at making my website compatibility, and with IE, the old jerk, I need to use

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>

<![endif]-->
```

However, as "lte IE8" means "equal to or less than IE8", how can IE6 even read this ?

Also, is it lt or lte ?
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html refers both, though only lte in it's definition.

Comment: Why would 6 have a problem knowing if it was less than 8?

Comment: Hmm, your question is weird, I think you don't need to bother how it can read it, it just works for IE8, 7, 6 and 5.5

Comment: IE6 knows its version is 6.  It is able to compare 6 lt 8 and determine that it is less than 8.  <!--[if lte IE 99]> should also work in IE 6

Comment: "Also, is it lt or lte ?" Both can be used, and mean (obviously) different things.

Comment: alright you smart guys, especially @Ed S. Why don't you just say it's a automatic function that compares versioning. Instead of asking a non-sense question back ..

Comment: Hardly a nonsense question... I mean, if you were implemnting this, how would you do it?

Comment: It is a nonsense question, as you can't assume other people have the same level of knowledge about something as you have. Answering with silly questions is not the way to help others. I asked because i wanted to be sure that it is right. If you have nothing else to do than going around and flam and giving stupid comments .. do so .. I have better things to do than this .. and yeah great vote down from you .. lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer one part of your question, which no-one seemed to answer explicitly and I have been trying to figure out ...

> is it lt or lte?

Without realising what lt and lte are, you might be unsure which to use, however from reading other comments, I realised that **lt = less than** and **lte = less than or equal to** (similary gt and gte are greater than and greater than or equal to), so it depends which versions of IE you want the rule to apply to as to whether you use lt, lte or a combination.

Answer (score 5):

Conditional comments are forwards-compatible. IE detects the number after the "IE" token and compares it to its current version. It doesn't have a built-in whitelist "IE7, IE8" or anything. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can look at it as an expression:

```
<!--[if expression]> HTML <![endif]-->
```

Another example would also work:

```
<!--[if true]> HTML <![endif]-->
```

[About conditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)